# Return from Recursion (c/c++)

Tags: c++, c, recursion, return, return-value

I'm having trouble returning a desired value in a recursive call. I want it to always return 0 unless a certain condition is met, in that case it should return 1 and exit.

```
int check = recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);
int recursion(int *a, int *b, int c, int d, int e, int f){
    int k, dX, dY;
    for(k=0;k<=b[1]-1;k++){
        dX = b[k*4+3] - e;
        dY = b[k*4+2] - f;
        if(((dX == 1 || dX == -1) && (dY == 0))){
            if(b[k*4+4] == 1) return 1; 
            e = b[k*4+3];
            f = b[k*4+2];
            b[k*4+2] = b[k*4+3] = 0;
            recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);
        }
        if(((dY == 1 || dY == -1) && (dX == 0))){
            if(b[k*4+4] == 1) return 1;
            e = b[k*4+3];
            f = b[k*4+2];
            b[k*4+2] = b[k*4+3] = 0;
            recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);      
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

A lot of irrelevant information has been removed, but as you can see if b[k*4+4] == 1 at anypoint, check should then equal 1. Otherwise, return 0 and check will = 0. It completes a basic traversal, which I know is completing correctly and is even stopping at the terminating condition (b[k*4+4] == 1) but it isn't returning the correct value.

Currently, it is ALWAYS returning 0. Check always equals 0, although it is stopping once the condition is met. I also tried removing the ending return 0; although check still equals zero...

Comment: I know that I can pass a pointer to check and simply set check = 1 and then return. I can confirm that this **DOES** work, but was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this with returns.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the return values of your recursive calls, i.e.,

```
return recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);
```

Comment: This breaks the traversal and it doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `return recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);` instead of just `recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);`. Otherwise, the result of those recursive calls will be lost.

edit: to not prematurely exit your loop, you can do this:

```
int check = recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f);
int recursion(int *a, int *b, int c, int d, int e, int f){
    int k, dX, dY;
    for(k=0;k<=b[1]-1;k++){
        dX = b[k*4+3] - e;
        dY = b[k*4+2] - f;
        if(((dX == 1 || dX == -1) && (dY == 0))){
            if(b[k*4+4] == 1) return 1; 
            e = b[k*4+3];
            f = b[k*4+2];
            b[k*4+2] = b[k*4+3] = 0;
            if(recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f) == 1)
                return 1;
        }
        if(((dY == 1 || dY == -1) && (dX == 0))){
            if(b[k*4+4] == 1) return 1;
            e = b[k*4+3];
            f = b[k*4+2];
            b[k*4+2] = b[k*4+3] = 0;
            if(recursion(a, b, c, d, e, f) == 1)
                return 1;   
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This breaks the traversal and it doesn't complete.

Comment: you still need to find a way to use your recursive call. At the moment all you are doing is calling the function and then discarding the return, which is effectively useless. Perhaps you want to set a flag that conditionally switches to 1, then you can return that at the end of your function?

Comment: That makes sense. Utilizing a flag that passes through to future calls and returns upon exit would work. Thanks @Red Alert!

Comment: Now that I think about it you don't even need a flag, if you did `if( recursion(...) == 1){ return 1; }`, you'd get the desired functionality.